# The behavior class passed to Actor.addBehavior was null. Superpowers

Tags: typescript

Superpowers game engine.

---

### TypeScript.

---

### Game script

```
let MainChar = new Sup.Actor("Main Character");
new Sup.SpriteRenderer(MainChar, "Leonard");

let CameraMan = new Sup.Actor("Camera Man");
new Sup.Camera(CameraMan);

MainChar.setPosition(0, 0, 0);
CameraMan.setPosition(0, 0, 5);

MainChar.addBehavior(CharacterBehavior);
```

---

### Character script

```
class CharacterBehavior extends Sup.Behavior {
 update() {
  if(Sup.Input.isKeyDown("LEFT")){
   this.actor.move(-0.1, 0, 0);
 }

  if(Sup.Input.isKeyDown("RIGHT")){
   this.actor.move(0.1, 0, 0);
  }
 }
 }
Sup.registerBehavior(CharacterBehavior);
```

### issue

```
Game.ts:12 Uncaught Error: The behavior class passed to Actor.addBehavior was null. Make sure the class is declared before     Actor.addBehavior is called.Actor.addBehavior @ VM148:527(anonymous function) @ Game.ts:12start @ runtime.js:61310(anonymous function) @ SupRuntime.js:1826(anonymous function) @ SupRuntime.js:206async.forEachOf.async.eachOf @ SupRuntime.js:258async.forEach.async.each @ SupRuntime.js:234Player._startPlugins @ SupRuntime.js:1823(anonymous function) @ SupRuntime.js:1698(anonymous function) @ SupRuntime.js:743iterate @ SupRuntime.js:287Item.run @ SupRuntime.js:1446drainQueue @ SupRuntime.js:1416
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt2f5.png)

how to fix? i'm new in TypeScript, and there used "export" and "import", but it doesnt work.

Comment: the decision is to put Game script below Character script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the decision is to put Game script below Character script

Answer (score 0):

Why is your `import { CharacterBehavior } ...` commented out?